# How to register for a multicast DNS service in a chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, bonjour

I'm using [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/mdns-browser) example chrome app as base to browse multicast DNS. It is working quite well and gives me service name and IP of the service provider.

How do I register for a service so that other devices such as Android NSD or Apple Bonjour could discover my chrome app?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out as well.   I don't know if it is possible.

I also want to point out that the multicast DNS chrome app doesn't work on chrome OS.  It seems there some bug in chrome os that prevents .local from resolving.

So if need chrome os support, I don't think there is any way to do mdns right now.

Here's a thread on the chrome app google group where it is thoroughly discussed:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/apps-dev/slnIoz6KOCk/r2PvG1v3wKMJ

Also in that thread, it seems there is a chrome.mdns api that they want to expose to solve all of this, but no real confirmation that they are going to do it soon.